What "methods" does a multivariate Moment-Generating Function provide?
I don't think the Probability and Random Variables course I studied really touched on multivariate Moment-Generating Functions at all, and Wikipedia appears surprisingly silent on this question.  The usual thing to do with a univariate MGF is to take derivatives of $M(s)$ (I will write it without subscript and reserve subscripting $M$ for partial derivative notation) with respect to $s$ then set $s$ to $0$ to obtain raw moments, or take derivatives of $e^{-\mu s}M(s)$ with respect to $s$ then set $s$ to $0$ to obtain central moments (or divide the central moments by $\sigma^\text{derivative order}$ to obtain standardized moments).
I want to understand how this extends to the multivariate case.  For the raw analogs, I have found that in higher dimensions, there are scalar-valued moments and scalar-valued cross-moments which are jointly in one-to-one correspondence with the mixed partial derivatives of $M(\vec s)$, i.e., there is a cross-moment $M_{s_1 s_1 s_2}(\vec s)\ |_{\vec s = \vec 0}$.  Some of these are recognizably-named quantities, such as covariances.  There are also non-scalar-valued moments (and perhaps cross-moments?) to be accounted for, such as the "overall" mean of the multivariate probability distribution, which is a vector.  The most natural idea to compute this mean, $\nabla M(\vec s)\ |_{\vec s = \vec 0}$, seems to do the trick.  Similarly, the covariance matrix seems to be given by Hessian$(M(\vec s))\ |_{\vec s = \vec 0}$.  I'm not sure about higher-orders.
A hint of a pattern thus far is that the collection of scalar-valued moments and scalar-valued cross-moments constitute the elements of the non-scalar-valued moments.  Also just the basic pattern of hitting $M(\vec s)$ with operators from differential multivariate calculus and setting all inputs to $0$.  Perhaps Laplacian$(M(\vec s))\ |_{\vec s = \vec 0}$, Jacobian$(M(\vec s))\ |_{\vec s = \vec 0}$, etc., give more exotic kinds of moments.
For central moments, my hypothesis based upon pattern matching is that for any of the above moments, its central version is computed the same way but by first multiplying $M(\vec s)$ by $e^{-\vec \mu\ \cdot\ \vec s}$ (thus $M_{s_1 s_1 s_2}(\vec s)\ |_{\vec s = \vec 0}$ becomes $[e^{-\vec \mu\ \cdot\ \vec s} M]_{s_1 s_1 s_2}(\vec s)\ |_{\vec s = \vec 0}$), and for standardized moments, that the central moment should be divided by the standard deviations corresponding to the mix of partial derivatives (so the aforementioned would become $\frac{[e^{-\vec \mu\ \cdot\ \vec s} M]_{s_1 s_1 s_2}(\vec s)\ |_{\vec s = \vec 0}}{\sigma_1\ ^2\ \ \sigma_2}$).
Is the above on the right track, and what is it missing?  If the multivariate MGF was a class in an object-oriented programming language, what are the methods it would have (related to querying it for moments and moment-like mathematical objects) and the corresponding mathematical operations to implement them?
